# Check if Current Category has Children

Tags: custom-taxonomy, get-children

I need to tell whether or not the current custom taxonomy archive page I'm viewing has child categories. I've got a situation where there are a lot of custom categories with children and the site is only to show posts at the end of the line. Otherwise it should show a link to the category that's the next step down. I've found this snippet, but it doesn't seem to work for custom taxonomies.

```
function category_has_children() {
global $wpdb;   
$term = get_queried_object();
$category_children_check = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = '$term->term_id' ");
    if ($category_children_check) {
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}   

<?php
    if (!category_has_children()) {
        //use whatever loop or template part here to show the posts at the end of the line
   get_template_part('loop', 'index'); 
       }   

    else {
       // show your category index page here
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There may or may not be a better way to do this, but here's how I would do it:

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
// print_r($children); // uncomment to examine for debugging
if($children) { // get_terms will return false if tax does not exist or term wasn't found.
    // term has children
}
```

If current taxonomy term has children the `get_terms` function will return an array, otherwise it will return `false`.

Tested and works on my local vanilla install with [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin used for CPT generation.

Comment: When I uncommented the print_r($children).... it outputted an array. How could that be turned into an if/else? Sorry, I'm still very new to php

Comment: Disregard I used this: if ($children) {
     echo 'Children Here';
    }
    else {
     echo 'No Children';
    }

Comment: @user29489 You're right, I wasn't clear enough in my answer. Edited for future reference.

Comment: For those that just need to know whether there are any children and don't need to get the data for the child terms, I suggest adding `'field' => 'count'` to just count the number of children.

Comment: Does this work with normal post categories as well?

Answer (score 14):

There's also a generic WP possibility to do this via [get_term_children](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/).

```
<?php
$children = get_term_children($termId, $taxonomyName);

if( empty( $children ) ) {
    //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to filter your terms to only show terms that either have children or not, you can actually use the `childless` parameter in your `get_terms()` function.

```
$children = get_terms( 
    'taxonomy' => '$taxonomy_slug',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'childless' => true
  ) 
);
```

This will output an array of terms that don't have children.

Answer (score -1):

This is by far the cleanest solution

```
$term = get_queried_object();
if($term->parent == 0 ){
  // do stuff;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `$term->parent == 0` will tell you whether or not the category _is_ a child, but not that it _has_ children. As an example, the stock `Uncategorized` category would pass your test, but it has no children.